# How to use multiple postDelayed handler inside a switch case to display pictures

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I'm developing a speech recognition app that will display a picture if I say some certain words. I am currently using postDelayed handler in each case so there is some delays between each picture. The problem is, if I say 2 or more words, only the last picture shows up. Here is the code:

```
private void imageLoader(String resultSpeech){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    String[] resultSplit = resultSpeech.split("\\s");
    for (int i=0; i < resultSplit.length; i++) {
        switch(resultSplit[i]) {
            case "hello":
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadImage("www.example.com/hello.jpg");
                    }
                }, 3000);
                break;

            case "bye":
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadImage("www.example.com/bye.jpg");
                    }
                }, 3000);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This one is for the speech recognition result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                String resultSpeech = result.get(0);
                imageLoader(resultSpeech);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to use delay for showing image?

Comment: @javadroid the images will contain some information so the user will have time to see it thoroughly first

Comment: i think you implement wrong logic. first of all call `loadImage` then on the `run()` method that triggered after 3 second hide that, and for your problem that say only last image showed: from your implementation its true. if i say three words, what you expect to be happen?

Comment: i tried what you said, but still only the last picture showed and after 3 seconds disappeared. If i say 3 words, it should load 3 images.

Comment: for your logic (say 3 word, load 3 image) you must create a queue for showing image. create a loader method. this method shows every image in a queue. your queue can be created in a stack object. when the one image from stack is showed next one is fetched and showed. and in the recognition method just add your images in queue (the stack object). hope to help you.